# malloc causing a SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault

Tags: c, malloc

```
typedef struct Matrix
{
    double * matrix;
    int sizex;
    int sizey;
}Matrix;

int nn = 257;
Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix *));
g->matrix = malloc(sizeof(double) * nn * nn);
g->sizex = nn;
g->sizey = nn;
```

This code give an error when it gets to `g->matrix = malloc(sizeof(double) * nn * nn);`
anyone see a problem with it ?

edit: found problem to be accessing unallocated memory in a place before the allocation shown, it was causing a SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: : C++ I think. @Abraham Adam: when you use C++ compiler, you have to explicitely cast the result of second malloc to `(double*)`.

Comment: thanks for all your helps I narrowed down the problem to sizeof(double), i can just replace it by 8, but not sure why that would be causing a problem.

Comment: Its a space problem on my machine I believe because it works when i decrease the space that I am allocating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass `malloc` the sizeof the `Matrix` not sizeof *pointer* to the `Matrix`.

Change

```
Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix *));
                                           ^^
```

to

```
Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

Also you **must** always check the return value of `malloc` and make sure allocation succeed before you go and use the allocated memory.

Comment: Don't forget to add *not* to cast the returned `void*`

Comment: I changed it too malloc(sizeof(Matrix)); still getting same problem

Comment: @Abraham Adam: Check if `malloc` is failing.

Comment: changed to Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
 if (g != NULL){
 g->matrix = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * nn * nn);
 g->sizex = nn;
 g->sizey = nn;
 } doesnt give back null still failing in same spot

Comment: How do you know it's failing? What error do you see? And what compiler are you using ?

Comment: gives No source available for "0x7ffff7851a98" . this compiles , fails at runtime with that error

Comment: i am using gcc on a linux machine

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using some ancient 16-bit compiler, probably Turbo C. Junk it and get gcc, either djgpp if you want to build DOS programs or mingw or cygwin if you want to build Windows programs.

Assuming I'm right, 257*257 overflows the maximum addressable size, 65536, not to mention what happens when you multiply it by 8.

**Edit:** OP changed the question after I wrote this so it may be completely off. If so I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix *));
```

This reserves enough heap space for a pointer to a Matrix, but you want enough heap space for the Matrix itself.  Try:

```
Matrix* g = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

For a complete, working program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Matrix {
    double * matrix;
    int sizex;
    int sizey;
} Matrix;

int main()
{
    int nn = 257;
    Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if (g == NULL)
    {
        printf("g = malloc() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    g->matrix = malloc(sizeof(double) * nn * nn);
    g->sizex = nn;
    g->sizey = nn; 
    printf("g %p, g->matrix %p, g->sizex %d, g->sizey %d\n",
            g, g->matrix, g->sizex, g->sizey);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my Linux box:

```
g 0x8822008, g->matrix 0xf6ea6008, g->sizex 257, g->sizey 257
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix *));
```

should be

```
Matrix * g = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

You're only allocating the size of a pointer to Matrix, rather than a Matrix itself.

Answer (score 0):

You do not allocate memory for a `Matrix` object, you are allocating for a pointer.

Change your first `malloc` call to do this:

`Matrix * g = malloc(sizeof(*g));`

I prefer this style as you do not need explicit pointer cast from `void *` in C, and you are allowed to do `sizeof` on the variable's underlying type. This could save you headaches just in case you change the type of `g` (or for future code).

Similarly for style:

`g->matrix = malloc(sizeof(double) * nn * nn);`

should be:

`g->matrix = malloc(sizeof(*(g->matrix)) * nn * nn);`

Answer (score 0):

Parameter of your `sizeof` should not be a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add the direction of not casting malloc's return. It is unnecessary, pollutant, and might lead to unwanted behavior (as described here: http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html